# Difference between v2 and v5 timeframes

Tags: pine-script

How do I match the time frame in v2 with time frame in v5

```
@version=2
tim=input('375')

//@version=5
//tim=input('375')

out1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,tim, close, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same input but the functionality of the `security()` function has changed from v2 to v3. Please see [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/appendix/Pine_version_3_migration_guide.html#pine-version-3-migration-guide).